# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack psychopy: haven't touched the script since it was working yesterday and am suddenly getting this error

Tags: python, psychopy

I recognize there are a decent amount of ValueError questions on here, but it seems none are specifically related to psychopy or my issue. I am coding an experiment from scratch on psychopy (no builder involved). Yesterday, my script was running totally fine. Today I tried running it without adding anything new or taking anything away and it's suddenly giving me this error:

```py
File "/Users/vpam/Documents/fMRI_binding/VSTMbindingpaige.py", line 53, in <module>
  script, filename = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

These are lines 52 and 53, apparently something in 53 (the last one) is making this happen, but I can't imagine what since it was working just fine yesterday. Anyone know why it's doing that? (I am running the oldest version of python in order to be able to include corrective audio feedback, but I have been running it on that with success):

```py
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
```

This is what I'm calling the filename (in the script it is above those other lines)

```py
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
from psychopy import gui
myDlg = gui.Dlg(title="Dr. S's experiment")
myDlg.addField('Subject ID','PJP')
ok_data = myDlg.show()
if myDlg.OK:
     print(ok_data)
else:
print('user cancelled')
[sID]=myDlg.data
# Data file name stem = absolute path + name; later add .psyexp, .csv, .log, etc
data_file = sID + '_VSTMbinding.txt'
f = open(data_file,'a') #name file here
f.write(sID)
print myDlg.data
```

Comment: How are you calling the script? That seems to indicate that you're not supplying enough command-line arguments.

Comment: Please put code in your questions. As you can see, it formats terribly in comments. How are you running your script? Basically it looks like you are doing `python script_name.py` instead of `python script_name.py some_file_name`

Comment: Quite clearly, argv is returning a single value. You are trying to unpack a single value into two variables. It's not going to work.

Comment: Then why would it have ran the experiment in the past? It did everything correctly numerous times before.

Comment: @boxcar44 because you probably provided command line arguments in the past. You need to provide a filename as an argument to the program...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Python2. Python3 gives a more detailed information in it's error message. The problem is that argv only contains a single value and you're trying to unpack it into two variables. `argv` contains the command line variables -- if this was running yesterday "without any changes" as you suggest, it's because you were providing a filename as a command-line argument.

### py2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print("Script: {0}\nFilename: {1}".format(script, filename))
```

### py3.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print("Script: {0}\nFilename: {1}".format(script, filename))
```

### Running py2.py:

```
$ charlie on laptop in ~
❯❯ ./py2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py2.py", line 4, in <module>
    script, filename = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

$ charlie on laptop in ~
❯❯ ./py2.py filename
Script: ./py2.py
Filename: filename
```

### Running py3.py:

```
$ charlie on laptop in ~
❯❯ ./py3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py3.py", line 4, in <module>
    script, filename = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

$ charlie on laptop in ~
❯❯ ./py3.py filename
Script: ./py3.py
Filename: filename
```